# Migration from java 8 to java 11

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

Is it recommended to migrate Java8 application to Java11?  and why? do you find that there's a lot of interesting functionalities  added to Java11 that are more performant than functionalities in Java8

Comment: Should you be using Java 7 or 6? (sure, my question is absurd, but are you using java 8 because that's what your project started with or did you upgrade to it?). The mere fact that support for Java 8 will end before support for Java 11 is sufficient enough motivation (not to mention a ton of new language features added starting with Java 9).

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: Like with any older software version, support will stop one day and you'll not get bugfixes and security updates anymore. So, eventually you will need to migrate from Java 8 to something newer. Since Java 11 is the current long term support release of Java, it makes sense to upgrade to Java 11 if you can.

Comment: Modules offer better organization and better security.  You don’t have to use modules in Java 9+ programs, but you can and you should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it recommended to migrate Java8 application to Java11? and why?

**Yes**, because :

- It is the latest free JDK release from Oracle under an open source license,
- There are many bugs fixed in Java 11, read [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/11-0-2-bugfixes-5209269.html)
- There are many new features, check [here](https://dzone.com/articles/90-new-features-and-apis-in-jdk-11)